# Preliminary creation of mipmap with function glGenerateMipmap()

Tags: java, android, kotlin, opengl-es

Created mipmap in Android (OpenGL ES 2.0/3.0) using the glGenerateMipmap() command:

```
public class Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer { 
    private final int textureID;
    public Renderer(Context context) {
        textureID = loadTexture(bitmap)
    }
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) { // render loop
        ...
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        // use bilinear interpolation
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
        ...
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, NUMBER_INDICES, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        ...
    }
}
```

Function to load texture (Kotlin):

```
private fun loadTexture(bitmap: Bitmap): Int {
    val textureId = IntArray(1)
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureId, 0)
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId[0])
    // loading two-dimensional texture image
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0)
    // set filtering modes
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST)
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR)
    return textureId[0]
}
```

As a result, artifacts disappeared, i.e. mipmap is works.  But when using several 3D-objects with textures on some physical devices there is a slowdown in rendering (FPS reduction). I associate this with mipmap generation in the render loop:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {  
    GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D)
}
```

**Question:** is it possible to do mipmap generation in advance (before the start of the rendering loop), for example in a loadTexture() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added glGenerateMipmap() command to the end of the loadTexture() function:

```
...
GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D)
return textureId[0]
...
```

And removed glGenerateMipmap() command from the function onDrawFrame(). I'm not completely sure that this is correct, but it seems to work well.